# Swift 3 enum with associated value AND function comparison

Tags: swift, if-statement, swift3, syntax, enums

I have this struct that has an enum property as well as a function:

```
struct UserInput {
  enum State {
    case unrestricted
    case restricted(because: WarningType)

    enum WarningType {
      case offline
      case forbidden
    }
  }

  var config: UserInputConfig?
  var state: State = .unrestricted

  func isConfigured() -> Bool {
    // Arbitrary checks about the config...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite the following conditionals so that the check for `isConfigured()` and `state` are in the same statement?

```
if case .restricted = userInput.state {
  return 1
} else if userInput.isConfigured() {
  return 1
} else {
  return 0
}
```

It seems because the `State` enum uses associated values, you cannot simply write `if userInput.state == .restricted || userInput.isConfigured()`, you need to use the `if case` syntax. There must be a way around this?

Comment: I added a *multi-clause condition* method to my answer which is shorter and easier to read and it short circuits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like to do this:

```
if case .restricted = userInput.state || userInput.isConfigured() {
    return 1
} else {
    return 0
}
```

but there is currently no way to do an *OR* with *pattern matching*. There are a couple of ways of doing *AND*.

By using [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you can turn `if a || b` into `if !(!a && !b)` and by reversing the *then* and *else* clauses of your `if` statement, you can just check for `if !a && !b`.

Unfortunately, you can't say `if !(case .restricted = userInput.state)`, but since your enum has only 2 cases, you can replace that with `if case .unrestricted = userInput.state`.

Now, how do you use that with another statement?  You can't use `&&` for the same reason you can't use `||`.

You can check for the failing case by using a pattern that matches both failing conditions (which is using *AND*) and then return `1` if both failing conditions aren't met:

```
if case (.unrestricted, false) = (userInput.state, userInput.isConfigured()) {
    return 0
} else {
    return 1
}
```

---

Equivalently you can use a *multi-clause condition*:

```
if case .unrestricted = userInput.state, !userInput.isConfigured() {
    return 0
} else {
    return 1
}
```

In addition to being shorter and IMO easier to read, this second method can *short circuit* and skip calling `userInput.isConfigured` in the case where `case .unrestricted = userInput.state` fails.

Comment: This would essentially act as an `&&` though, not `||`?

Comment: That is correct.  I've essentially replaced (a || b) with !(!a && !b) which is equivalent according to DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it really cleanly with a `switch` statement, and pattern matching:

```
switch userInput.state
{
   case .unrestricted:
        return userInput.isConfigured() ? 1 : 0;

   case .restricted(_):
        return 1
}
```